# WebStorm - customize the test command

Tags: webstorm

[image]

As seen on the picture, WebStorm starts test via `react-scripts test --testNamePattern=pattern`
However, given I use `craco` to override the webpack config, and that typically I use `env-cmd` to load environment variables (for example, `env-cmd -f .env.staging && yarn test`), I'd like to customize the test command.

For now, changing it to `craco test --testNamePattern=pattern` would be enough.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `node_modules/@craco/craco` as **Jest package:** in your **Jest** run configuration:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to change the command in the configuration settings, by changing the `Jest package` field.